# Llamar un metodo con un boton

Tags: java, poo, netbeans

quisiera saber si es posible llamar un metodo de una clase a un formulario desde un boton en concreto este

Metodo

```
package Variables;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 *
 * @author Nana
 */
public class func extends conexion {
    
    
     
       public boolean InsertarDatos(users pro)
       {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con= getConnection();
        
           String sql = ("INSERT INTO funcionariosb(Cargo_funcionario,identificacion_funcionario,nombre_funcionario,telefono_funcionario,direccion_funcionario,correo_funcionario,contra_funcionario  )VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
           
           try{
               ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               
           
        ps.setString(1,pro.getC());
        ps.setString(2,pro.getIDD());
        ps.setString(3,pro.getN());
        ps.setString(4,pro.getT());
        ps.setString(5,pro.getD());
        ps.setString(6,pro.getCo());
        ps.setString(7,pro.getCont());

                


        ps.execute();
        return true;
        
       }catch(SQLException e){
System.err.println(e);
return false;

       }finally{
               try{
                   con.close();
                   
               }catch(SQLException e)
       {
           System.err.println(e);

       }
           }
       }
}
```

Quiero llamarlo desde aqui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```
package Variables;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 *
 * @author Nana
 */
public class func extends conexion {
    
    
     
       public boolean InsertarDatos(users pro)
       {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con= getConnection();
        
           String sql = ("INSERT INTO funcionariosb(Cargo_funcionario,identificacion_funcionario,nombre_funcionario,telefono_funcionario,direccion_funcionario,correo_funcionario,contra_funcionario  )VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
           
           try{
               ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
               
           
        ps.setString(1,pro.getC());
        ps.setString(2,pro.getIDD());
        ps.setString(3,pro.getN());
        ps.setString(4,pro.getT());
        ps.setString(5,pro.getD());
        ps.setString(6,pro.getCo());
        ps.setString(7,pro.getCont());

                


        ps.execute();
        return true;
        
       }catch(SQLException e){
System.err.println(e);
return false;

       }finally{
               try{
                   con.close();
                   
               }catch(SQLException e)
       {
           System.err.println(e);

       }
           }
       }
}
```

Debes de instanciar la clase que quieres poner en funcion. Dentro del ActionPerformed colocar lo siguiente:

```
func obj1 = new func();
obj1.InsertarDatos(//aqui el objeto que le vas  pasar por parametro);
```

Quedaría algo como esto:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    
    //INSTANCIAR LA CLASE
    func obj1 = new func();
    obj1.InsertarDatos(//aqui el objeto que le vas  pasar por parametro);

}
```